# What is the essence of Google Chrome’s new controversial sign-in feature?

Tags: authentication, web-browser, chrome, single-sign-on, chromium

What is the essence of Google Chrome’s new controversial sign-in feature?

How does it work and how does it differ from what was it before?

What is the danger of it?

Is Chromium affected?

Comment: Earlier when the user would login to YouTube or Gmail, he would then be logged into the Chrome browser too. The concern was that this automatic sign-in function meant that data was being uploaded to Google's servers without user's knowledge, as he hadn't specifically given permission to let it sign them in.

Google is also updating its sync UI to make it clearer over whether you’re syncing data like passwords, credit cards, addresses, and browsing history to a Google Account.